# Function that return all attributes from class members

Tags: c#

Let's say I have class

```
class A 
{
    [Attribute1]
    [AttributeN]
    bool Prop {get;set;}

}

void Main ()
{
    A a;
    var attrs = GetAttributes(a.Prop);
}
```

Which is the best way to implement function GetAttributes?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
Let me be more specific, I know that need to use reflaction 
1. I don;t watn to use string as method name
2. it should not depend from type, should be generic function

```
function GetAttr<...>(...)
{
    ....
    typeof(<get from param>).GetMethod(<figure out from parameters>).GetAttributes()
}

// Ideally I want to call GetAttr like below 
A1 a1
GetAttr(a1.Prop1)

B2 b2
GetAttr(b2.Prop2)
```

Comment: Is property public or private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create extension method which will accept property selector expression (thus you will avoid hard-coding property name as string):

```
public static IEnumerable<Attribute> GetPropertyAttributes<T, TProp>(
    this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> propertySelector)
{
    Expression body = propertySelector;
    if (body is LambdaExpression)
        body = ((LambdaExpression)body).Body;

    if (body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var pi = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)body).Member;
    return pi.GetCustomAttributes();
}
```

Usage:

```
A a = new A();
var attributes = a.GetPropertyAttributes(x => x.Prop);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is close to what I want

Comment: @vitaly that is not close.That is what you want, and what you can do.

Comment: @Sergey I can't vote up because of daily vote limit :D this solution is more useful than mine.

Comment: @Selman22 thanks! I appreciate your attitude and it worth noting two things - your solution can analyze non-public properties and my day votes are not ended yet :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var attrs = typeof(A).GetProperty("Prop",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     .GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

If you want to do it with a custom method, then you can define a simple method:

```
public static object[] GetAttributes(Type type, string propertyName)
{
     var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
     if (prop != null)
     {
         return prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
     }
     else
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

And overloaded version for `BindingFlags`

```
public static object[] GetAttributes(Type type, string propertyName,BindingFlags flags)
{
     var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName,flags);
     if (prop != null)
     {
         return prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
     }
     else
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var attrs = GetAttributes(typeof(A), "Prop");
```

Or:

```
var attrs = GetAttributes(typeof(A), "Prop",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: I know this approach, I don;t to pass string as method name, see the Sergey Berezovskiy answer. Anyway thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use Reflection to achieve your goal. In this case you need to tak advantage of two Reflection methods, namely `GetProperty` and `GetCustomAttributes`:

```
class A 
{
    [Attribute1]
    [AttributeN]
    bool Prop {get;set;}

}

void Main ()
{
    A a;
    var attrs = typeof(A).GetProperty("Prop").GetCustomAttributes();
}
```

Comment: yes I undesrtand that I need to use reflaction, but I want have functtion in format as in question function F(...) { here code with reflaction and all required stuff }, I want to not pass (at least explicitly) method member and type, I will edit my answer...